# insert or replace id exists or is difrent

Tags: php, sql

I have this code in php to insert into database

```
$sqlx="INSERT INTO bruno_wallet (foto, data, nome, evento,horarios,obs,horas,valorhora,totalparcial,props,id_do_mes,nome_id ) 
VALUES ('$ii', '$data','$nome[0]','$evento' ,'$horarios','$obs','$numeros_horas','$valor_horas','$total_parcial','$props',' $id_postt','$nomeid') " ;
```

but it always inserts news values.
I want to : insert if its new and replace if old values if it exists

Comment: I'd also suggest to make your database design better, so there is no need for deleting or replacing. It's safer (less chance to loose data).

Comment: yes it is possible if you are using only Primary key not any other key like unqieu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE** if you have only primary key in table.

**Note than: if you have any other key like Unique Key etc than it will not work.**

```
$sqlx="INSERT INTO bruno_wallet (foto, data, nome, evento,horarios,obs,horas,
    valorhora,totalparcial,props,id_do_mes,nome_id ) 
VALUES ('$ii', '$data','$nome[0]','$evento' ,'$horarios','$obs',
    '$numeros_horas','$valor_horas','$total_parcial','$props','$id_postt','$nomeid') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
foto = '$ii', data = '$data', nome = '$nome[0]', evento = '$evento', horarios = '$horarios',
obs = '$obs', horas = '$numeros_horas', valorhora = '$valor_horas', 
totalparcial = '$total_parcial', props = '$props', id_do_mes = '$id_postt', nome_id = '$nomeid'
";
```

**Explanation:**

> From dev.mysql.com: You can use the VALUES(col_name) function in the
>   UPDATE clause to refer to column values from the INSERT portion of the
>   INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

If foto is a primary key than after ist insertion every time this query will update the record.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using the `INSERT` command then. First find if it already is in your database then insert or leave it as it is.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that this way, an INSERT command is always an additional row in your database. You can however do something with subqueries, But the better practice is to do this in code.

You should run SELECT using the columns and values you have, If exists run a insert else run a update.

The problem you present is impossible to solve, since the database will not have anything to update if all columns match, I hope you understand how that would work, and that the way you intend it is not logical. Also you are not mentioning what your "matchcolumns" are. so if what matches what it should be an update... 
If you do need to proceed this way, Please provide us more information so we can assist

Answer (score 1):

Hi here is simple and easy solution try it.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bruno_wallet WHERE foto = '$ii' "); //in where condition add whatever condition you want

if( mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $sqlx = "UPDATE bruno_wallet SET foto ='$ii', data =  '$data', nome = '$nome[0]', evento = '$evento' ,horarios = '$horarios',obs = '$obs',horas = '$numeros_horas',valorhora = '$valor_horas',totalparcial = '$total_parcial',props = '$props',id_do_mes = ' $id_postt',nome_id = '$nomeid'  WHERE foto = '$ii' "; //in where condition add whatever condition you want
}
else
{
  $sqlx="INSERT INTO bruno_wallet (foto, data, nome, evento,horarios,obs,horas,valorhora,totalparcial,props,id_do_mes,nome_id ) 
VALUES ('$ii', '$data','$nome[0]','$evento' ,'$horarios','$obs','$numeros_horas','$valor_horas','$total_parcial','$props',' $id_postt','$nomeid') " ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MYSQL you can use INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE from [Mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

When doing an insert where a unique key is present the existing record will be updated with the fields you specify.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this is to check if the data sent exists in the database already. If the data is already in the database run an update query and run insert if not.

Run this first

```
Select * from bruno_wallet where nome_id='$nomeid';
```

Now fetch the data and set if to any variable. For this purpose am going to call it $info
Now run

```
if(!$info)
{
  "INSERT INTO bruno_wallet (foto, data, nome, evento,horarios,obs,horas,valorhora,totalparcial,props,id_do_mes,nome_id ) 
VALUES ('$ii', '$data','$nome[0]','$evento' ,'$horarios','$obs','$numeros_horas','$valor_horas','$total_parcial','$props',' $id_postt','$nomeid') " ;
 }else{
   Run update query
 }
```

`